# Why won't the importing of a file work in my Java program?

Tags: java, jfilechooser, java.util.scanner

I'm not sure why this code won't allow me to choose a file and then scan it. How can I debug it?

```
private String[][] importMaze(){
    String fileName;
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
          fileName = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();

    File f = new File(fileName);
    try {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(f);
        int rows = scan.nextInt();
        int columns = scan.nextInt();
        String [][] maze = new String[rows][columns];
        int r = 0;
        while(scan.hasNext() && r<=rows){
            for(int c = 0; c<=columns;c++){
                maze[r][c]=scan.next();
            }
            r++;
        }
        return maze;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  Are you getting an error, not the results you're expecting, or something else?

Comment: I was getting a "file not found" exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your code and it gets to the point where the dialog opens and you can select a file.

I think your problem lies here:

```
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
      fileName = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();

File f = new File(fileName);
```

The following code:

```
fileName = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();
```

returns only the NAME of the file, not the full file path. This in turn causes

```
File f = new File(fileName);
```

to not open the file you want it to, but to simple "create" (it does not actually create the file until you write it out) the file.

What you need to do is replace those three line with:

```
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
```

That would make f reference the file you chose.

Comment: Thank you for solving that problem for me!